# How to apply a value to a list of functions

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

What I'd like to achieve is:

```
apply :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
```

this is kind of the inverse of map:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

I've tried Hoogle, but to no avail. Can anyone suggest a clean way of doing this in Haskell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
apply :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
apply a = map ($ a)
```

which is a pithy way of saying

```
apply a = map (\f -> f a)
```

which may be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

`\a -> map ($ a)` is definitely fine, but perhaps yet a bit nicer is an [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html) approach: there is

```
<**> :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
```

which has an instance `<*> :: [a] -> [a->b] -> [b]`. Looks a lot like what you want! You just need to put your `a` value in a singleton list, for which there is also a dedicated function in `Applicative`: `pure`.

```
apply :: Applicative f => a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
apply = (<**>) . pure
```

Though actually, I would rather restrict the signature to `a -> [a->b] -> [b]` for this top-level binding, since `Applicative` makes it look like you have the most general signature possible, which it is not:

```
apply :: Functor f => a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
apply a = fmap ($ a)
```

Really, my solution is probably best when you're in some pipeline, I daresay it's best *not* to define `apply` but use `(<**>) . pure` directly in the code.

Comment: By the Applicative laws, `((<**>) . pure) y u == u <*> pure y == pure ($ y) <*> u == fmap ($ y) u` for all `Applicative`s, but the last is just more general.