# Functional Terminology: Mapping (SIMD) vs ??? (MISD)

Tags: functional-programming, terminology

Given that `map` normally means to apply a given function (`f(x)`) across lots of values (`[a,b,c,d]`) (analogous to Single Instruction Multiple Data architectures), the opposite could be a single value (`a`) applied across multiple functions (`f(x),g(x),h(x)`), analogous to Multiple Instruction Single Data architectures.

```
map(f,[a,b,c,d]) => [f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)]

???([f,g,h],a) => [f(a),g(a),h(a)]
```

Is there a generally accepted term for this second operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the same operation, namely, a `map`. But since you have to map the application *at* `a`, instead of the application *of* `f`, you need a lambda:

```
misd([f,g,h],a) == map(lambda op. op a, [f,g,h])
```

If the language in question has an "application operator" and supports partial application, like Haskell, you can simplify this ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868983/1346276)):

```
map ($a) [f, g, h]
```

Now, for the terms you propose: I don't know of them, and think that for a functional language, they don't make sense to be introduced. Remember, one of the crucial criterial for FP is *functions (= instructions) are data*. Blurring the distinction between "instruction" and "data", there is no need to distinguish multiple data and multiple instructions, since they are the same, in the end.

Of course, this holds only in an abstract sense. If you're going into parallelism, those terms are of course still useful in their conventional meaning, when it's useful to distinguish what is to be *applicated* from what the operations are being *applied to*. But now you know that you can turn that relation around, given the right means!